# How to create a file if it does not exist otherwise clear an existing file?

Tags: bash

I have a project that opens a file and writes some information to it. The file needs to exist, and needs to be empty. The file needs to be created the first time the program is run, and the file needs to be cleared for each successive run.

Is there an easy way in bash to create a file if it does not exist, else clear the contents of the existing file?

Comment: The standard way to create/truncate a file is `: > file`, see `man bash` under `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` describing the `':'` which is essentially a builtin that does nothing except return `0` (but provides a valid source for redirecting to create/truncate a file or create an infinite loop, e.g. `while : ; do...`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `echo` or any external utility, but just use the shell built-ins. Just use the shell re-direct operator (`> file`).

```
$ mkdir testDir    
$ cd testDir/
$ ls -l
total 0
$ > fileThatDoesNotExist
$ ls -1
fileThatDoesNotExist
```

It will work even if there are some contents in the file, it will truncate its content

```
$ echo 'whatever' > fileThatDoesNotExist
$ cat fileThatDoesNotExist
whatever
$ > fileThatDoesNotExist
$ cat fileThatDoesNotExist
```

Comment: Arguably `:>file` may be a more explicit way of doing it.